# Why does Rundeck NodeFirstWorkflowStrategy execute StepFirstWorkflowStrategy? The outcome is sometimes step first succeed but node first fails

Tags: rundeck

I have modified the Rundeck server version 2.5 source code to execute a job on 1 of the available nodes.  I have not tested to see if this issue I am getting is due to my source code change or if it is a bug in the Rundeck version 2.5 code.

The problem I am seeing is when a job completes all its steps successfully, it should exit with success.  That is sometimes not the case.  Sometimes the final exit status is failed even though debug shows that the steps exited with success.  I am trying to track down what is triggering this failed status.  Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: I should add that the job is configured as Node Oriented.

Comment: Also the code change I made randomly picks 1 node out of the set of available matched nodes.  It does not execute the job on more than 1 node.

Comment: For anyone familiar with the rundeck server code, somewhere in the execution of the nodefirststrategy vs stepfirststrategy, the workflowstatus is getting set to false.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the job doing? I had an issue similar to this where rundeck was reporting failures for what appeared to be successful runs. We were issuing puppet commands as a step in a job. We found that if puppet finishes cleanly and **doesn't** apply any changes exit status will be 0, Rundeck job is successful. However; puppet was returning an exit code of 2 for a clean puppet deploy that **did** make changes, resulting in a failed job with successful individual steps.

Not sure if this applies to your situation but hopefully it helps!